# MD5 returns different values for the same input

Tags: java, android, md5

I'm on Android, so it's just java, I have the same input strings, but getting different values each time. I am missing anything? Thanks

```
private String getShortenedKey(String key) {
        String shortenedKey=null;
        MessageDigest md = null;
        LogUtils.LOGD(HASH_ALGO, "before key: "+ System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            shortenedKey = key;
        }
        LogUtils.LOGD(HASH_ALGO, "after key: "+ System.currentTimeMillis());

        md.update(key.getBytes());
        byte[] shortenedBytes = md.digest();
        shortenedKey = String.valueOf(shortenedBytes);
        return shortenedKey;
    }
```

Input string:

```
{"config":{"wp":"(1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000)","v":"8","unit":"auto","ef":true,"ws":1,"tt":0,"cs":1},"items":[{"startTime":1409180400,"id":"WorkXYZ@habit.skedgo.com_1409180400","class":"event","endTime":1409209200,"location":{"lng":151.20785,"lat":-33.85926},"priority":0},{"startTime":1409148000,"id":"HomeXYZ@habit.skedgo.com_1409148000","class":"event","endTime":1409234340,"location":{"lng":151.18089,"lat":-33.89153},"priority":0}]}
```

**Update:** so many valid answers, thanks. I pick the one that is easiest to change. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the modified version.
you could use base64 encoding for bytes

```
private String getShortenedKey(String key) {
    String shortenedKey=null;
    MessageDigest md = null;
    LogUtils.LOGD(HASH_ALGO, "before key: "+ System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        md.update(key.getBytes());
        byte[] shortenedBytes = md.digest();
        shortenedKey = Base64.encodeToString(shortenedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        shortenedKey = key;
    }
    LogUtils.LOGD(HASH_ALGO, "after key: "+ System.currentTimeMillis());

    return shortenedKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
shortenedKey = String.valueOf(shortenedBytes);
```

is not doing what you think.

In order to get a string representation of the byte values inside the array you need to implement a little utility method.

Furthermore, if the call to `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");` ever throws a `NoSuchAlgorithmException` your program will crash a little later here `md.update(key.getBytes());` with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks, I already tracked `NoSuchAlgorithmException` and use the original key if that happens.

Answer (score 1):

As @Henry explained the issue at his answer, `String.valueOf(shortenedBytes)` must be changed.

Replace this;

```
shortenedKey = String.valueOf(shortenedBytes);
```

to this;

```
shortenedKey = new String(Base64.encode(shortenedBytes))
```

You can use Base64 from [Bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

[Download the jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on)